# Role cannot be used to create content without having administer permissions

Tags: 7, users, organic-groups

I am using Organic Groups on a Drupal 7 website. I created a Group content type and a few user roles.

I want to make sure that a user role can create and edit the Group content, but not delete it. I enabled all necessary permissions, but I get an internal server error when trying to create the content.

However, when I add the *Administer Organic Groups permissions* permission to the role, users with that role can create content. An unwanted side-effect is that the role can also delete content.

How can a role be allowed to create Organic Groups content without having the permission to delete it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am using OG 7.2x, and ended up creating a custom Drupal role that had the permissions we wanted, without the delete (except for the ability to delete their own content). Would that work for you? I'm currently trying to get OG Roles to manage all of our permissions, but finding it is too granular, so looking for a solution to that issue. I'm open to suggestions :)